# Не работает namespaces в PHP

Tags: php, namespace, traits

Есть структура:

```
| - index.php
| - test
      | classes 
          |- someclass.php
      | traits
          |- sometrait.php
```

И код:

> (Index.php — работает)

```
<?php
    use \Test\Classes as Classes;
    use \Test\Traits as Traits;

    spl_autoload_register(...);

    echo Classes\Someclass::start();
?>
```

> (Someclass.php)

```
<?php
    namespace Classes; 
      // ^ не работает, но если я заменю "Classes" на "Test\Classes", то работает
      // Почему?
    Class Someclass
    {
        use Traits/Sometrait;
        // Да, не работает, но если я заменю "traits" на "Test\Traits" , то работает!
        // Почему?
        public static function start() {...}
    }
?>
```

Дело в том, что неймспейс в классе работает, только если писать полностью `Test\Classes`, а не `Classes`, та же проблема и с трейтами: `Traits` не работает, а вот `Test\Traits` очень даже.

Comment: Вам определенно сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вы поместили класс `Someclass` по пути test\classes\someclass.php относительно точки вызова в index.php. В принципе вы можете так поступать - это не запрещено - т.е. это работает, однако, вам придется прописать собственное правило автозагрузки такого класса в `spl_autoload_register()`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы автозагрузчик автоматически мог обнаружить ваш класс, вам придется поместить его в пространство имен `Test\Classes`. Более того, стандарт PSR-4 просто предписывает вам использование путей в пространстве имен, совпадающих с физическим путем к файлу с классом.